# BeautifulSoup get data without page structure

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Here is the webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--eBay V3- msxml 6.0 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-->
<!--srcId - File Exchange Programmatically Upload-->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Upload File Programmatically</title><script language="JavaScript"><!--
                                                                var pageName = "File Exchange Upload";

                                                        //--></script><script language="javascript" src="http://include.ebaystatic.com/js/e867/us/legacy/globals_e8672us.js"> </script><script src="http://include.ebaystatic.com/js/e885/us/legacy/common_functions_e8852us.js"> </script></head>
<body>
                                File upload successful. Your ref # is 711103172.<br><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="self.close();return false;">Close</a></body>
</html>
```

I need to extract just the number 711103172, would BeautifulSoup be suitable for this? Or some other method (I'm using BS at the moment however this page has little structure.

I could get the data within body to return this:

```
<body>
                                File upload successful. Your ref # is 711103172.<br><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="self.close();return false;">Close</a></body>
```

However once I get there I'm stuck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup` to get the `body` text, then use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract the desired number:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
    Your HTML code here
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
match = re.search(r'Your ref # is (\d+)', soup.body.text)
print match.group(1) if match else 'Not Found'
```

Prints:

```
711103172
```

FYI, `(\d+)` part of the regular expression is a [saving/capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping). `\d+` matches one or more digits.